# How to share a QListIterator between two member functions?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

I created a new class that inherits from Qlist. This new class has two member functions that need to iterate over the list in a forward manner and backward manner.

Now I am relativily new to c++ and Qt so my error my lurk in the declaration syntax, but I cannot got an iterator as a protected member variable declared that will compile.

In the class header I will have

```
[...]
public:
    MyObject* moveNext(); // this returns a pointer to next object
    MyObject* movePrev(); // this return a pointer to prev object

protected:
    QListIterator<MyObject *> i(*this); // this is where the problem is!!!
[...]
```

decrlaring the iterator inside the member functions defeat the purpose as one loses the position it was at previously...

Am I going about this the wrong way (by inheriting from QList and then wanting to have a itterator that is global and persistant to the list)?

Comment: What are you expecting the `(*this)` to do?

Comment: If I declare the iterator like this " QListIterator<MyObject *> i(*this);" inside the member function it compiles. If I remove the (*this) from the declaration in the header file it doesn't compile. QListIterator needs the list send to the constructor: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistiterator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your iterator `i` to move forward and backward its obviously possible. `QListIterator` supports both `++` and `--` operators.

The way you can do that is have QList as private member of your class (instead deriving from QList). As another private member you have your iterator like in snippet you posted.

```
class Foo {
    QList<MyObject*> list;
    QListIterator<MyObject*> it;
    public:
    MyObject* moveNext() { return *(++it); }
    MyObject* movePrev() { return *(--it); }
    Foo() : list(QList<MyObject*>()) {
        it = list.begin();
    }
};
```

However, initialization of variable inside class declaration is impossible. You have to do that in class constructor.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for the great reply I appreciate your assistance. So I take it that it is better to use a "have a" then "is a" when it comes to QList ;)

Comment: Herb Sutter in his books suggests that inheritance is highly overused. When you can do "has a" do it.